# Where can I find the new rare items and enemies in Terraria 1.0.3?

Tags: terraria

Terraria [changelog](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/1-0-3-change-log.19653/) for version 1.0.3 report:

> - Added two new rare enemies that can both be found underground.
> - NEW ITEM - (RARE and SECRET Item for casters) Go on! Find it!

What are these new items and where I can found them? And the new monsters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The new enemies are [Tim](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Tim) and the [Dead Miner](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Dead_Miner).  The new item is the [Wizard Hat](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Wizard_Hat), which is dropped by Tim.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a Monty Python reference

Comment: @Chris - guessing? What else could it be? :)

Answer (score -1):

The new enemies are Tim and The Groom and the item is the wizard hat dropped by Tim, The Groom is a stronger zombie that has a chance of spawning during a blood moon, and Tim is a zombie wizard sometimes spawning when underground he uses magic attacks and teleportation.

Comment: The Groom is an overworld, not underground enemy